# Draggable Method in Jquery-ui not working with created elements

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

I have an image that when i click on it , it should create a div and place it within a container (Parent div ) and make it Draggable.

The problem that i have included the jquery-ui and the jquery ; but still the draggable method not working, it succeeded to add the div in the container but it's not draggable.

here is jquery peace of code :

```
var $homy;
var texty;
function perform(){
$homy=$("<div class='cabine'></div>");
texty=$("<textarea class='sub'></textarea>");
$homy.append(texty);
$homy.draggable();
$homy.appendTo("#container");
}
```

here is the html part :

```
<div>
<img class="accept" src="done.png" onclick="perform()" width="40" height="40">
</div>
```

is there something wrong??

Comment: I do not see `#container` in your HTML. Where is this element? I suspect that the created items are unable to be appended as the target does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drag-able div was there, but textarea cannot be dragged because you type into it/ can re-size it. Just make it smaller than your inner div and give it some definition with borders.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b25tm9df/)

```
#container{
  border-style: solid;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
.cabine{
  border-style: solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-top:20px;
}
.sub{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-top:20px;
  resize: none;
}
```

To keep the inner div inside the outer, change `.draggable()`to

```
$homy.draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

Comment: No prob. Glad to help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, I do not see `#container` in your HTML. I suggest the following:

```
$(function() {
  var $homy, texty;
  function perform(e) {
    $homy = $("<div>", {
      class: "cabine",
      title: "Enter Caption"
    });
    texty = $("<textarea>", {
      class: "sub"
    });
    $(e.target).parent().append($homy);
    $homy.html(texty).dialog();
  }
  $("img.accept").click(perform);
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zsdnsskg/

This creates the `div` and `textarea`, appends them after the `img`, and kicks off `.dialog()`.

Hope that helps.